# Get foreign key(s) of entity from EDMX file

Tags: c#, linq

I try to get collection of FKs of entity from edmx file. I cannot find a method or property which return collection or only bool property to indicate the property of entity is FK.
I searched EntityContainer class in MetadataProperties and finded nothing. I searched in class Type in property GetProperties and same result, I cannot find method or property to indicate FK.
How I get FK or indication of FK of entity from edmx file?

Sorry my bad english.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, show to us the model, and what you have tried

Comment: DO you need the value of the property?

Comment: Model has over 10 thousend lines. I thing its not good to paste it here. I dont need the value, only some indication the property is foreign key. I search in EntityContainer.BaseEntitySets in assosiacations sets and in entity sets and in class typeof(Entity).Properties().

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Foriegn Key using reflection and filtering the properties on the [ForeignKeyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetForeignKeyProps(Type type) {
  return type.GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(ForeignKeyAttribute), false));
}
```

Usage, to get values:

```
var obj = new T();

var foreignKeyPropertyInfos = GetForeignKeyProps(typeof (T));
foreach (var foreignKeyPropertyInfo in foreignKeyPropertyInfos)
{
  var value = foreignKeyPropertyInfo.GetValue(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the ObjectSet (from older EF) which gives you access to the navigation properties. You can get your hands on it like this:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var os = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
var foreignKeyProperties = os.EntitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties.Where(x => x.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.One);
```

`db` is the `DBContext`, `TEntity` is the type of the entity you are using